# Modify decimal value in MySQL row by a random amount, different per row

Tags: mysql, random, decimal

I have a table comprising of 100's of rows, each with a "CurrentPrice" decimal(10,2) field.

What I want to do is subtract a certain amount from each CurrentPrice, and this amount will be randomly different per row.

The random amount will be limited to between 1% and 5% of the value of Current Price, but can consist of any decimal amount between those two percentages.

Thanks.

Comment: And where exactly is the problem?

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a a question?

Comment: @BillKarwin Killjoy ;-)

Comment: Apologies for not stating the question as such, but as Bill says above, it shouldn't be too hard to work out. I'll ride the humour though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UPDATE using the RAND() function. A new random number is returned on every call to the function, and the function is called once for each row matched by the UPDATE. So you get a different random amount each time.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Prices (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, CurrentPrice NUMERIC(9,2));

mysql> INSERT INTO Prices (CurrentPrice) VALUES (10), (10), (10);

mysql> SELECT * FROM Prices;
+----+--------------+
| id | CurrentPrice |
+----+--------------+
|  4 |        10.00 |
| 14 |        10.00 |
| 24 |        10.00 |
+----+--------------+

mysql> UPDATE Prices SET CurrentPrice = CurrentPrice * (0.99 - RAND()/25);
Query OK, 3 rows affected, 3 warnings (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 3

mysql> SELECT * FROM Prices;
+----+--------------+
| id | CurrentPrice |
+----+--------------+
|  4 |         9.95 |
| 14 |         9.52 |
| 24 |         9.73 |
+----+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for that Bill - perfect! Works a treat.